# Scrolling to elements in CKEditor via JavaScript

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

My CKEditor fields often contain lots of content with h1, h2, h3, etc headings, and I've written a script that presents all the headings in a sidebar for quick reference. I'd also like to use this sidebar as a navigation menu for the editor content, so clicking a heading in the sidebar scrolls the editor to the related heading, but I can't figure out how to wire it all up.

This post at https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-element-ckeditor leads me to believe that it should be possible, but I can't figure out how to get to the "editor" element described in the post.

My sidebar is built with jQuery from a CKEditor textarea with id="content" like this...

```
var content = $('<div/>').append($('#content').val());
var sidebar = "";
$(content).find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').addClass('heading');
$(content).find('.heading').each(function () {
  sidebar += this.outerHTML;
});
$('#sidebar').html(sidebar);
```

I imagine using jQuery :contains() to identify heading elements in the editor based on the text they contain, but I can't figure out how to hook back into the CKEditor instance in a way that enables this kind of DOM activity.

I am using CKEditor 4 but am happy to upgrade to version 5 if it offers a better solution to my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: In your case, the `editor` object described in the post you mention would be `CKEDITOR.instances.content`

Comment: @Wizard Thanks! I wound up going with $('#cke_content iframe').contents() in order to use JQuery find().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what wound up working for me:

```
  var content = $('<div/>').append($('#content').val());
  var sidebar = "";
  $(content).find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').addClass('heading');
  $(content).find('.heading').each(function () {
    sidebar += this.outerHTML;
  });
  $('#sidebar').html(sidebar);
  $('#sidebar .heading').click(function() {
      var element = $('#cke_content iframe').contents().find(':contains(' + $(this).text() + ')')[2];
      if (element) {
          element.scrollIntoView();
      }
  });
```